# Pass variable of a java file to feature file in java

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin

I am working on mobile automation using appium with Cucumber, I have to generate an email with random value on other java file i.e. `EmailUtils.java`

, whose method can be like this

```
public String generateEmail(){
      return emailAddress;
}
```

Now I have feature file:

```
Feature: Login User
   Scenario Outline:
    Given: Add "<Email>" address on field
Examples:
|Email|
| Add that value of generateEmail.java |
```

Is that achievable or do I need to create step method dedicatedly for this.

Comment: Is it something you have to do multiple times? Outlines are meant to capture different data driven flows.  In your case, is it a data driven case?

Answer (score 1):

You would say in your feature file that you are using a random email. The details don't matter, so don't mention those.

```
Feature: Login User
   Scenario: Login
    Given a user account with a random email and password
    When the credentials from the user account are used to login on the web
    Then a new web login event is emitted
```

If you want to know after the test what the credentials where you can use the `Scenario.log` method to add them into the Cucumber report.